# R shiny AngularJS working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, r, d3.js, shiny

I'm creating a dashboard with R and D3 running with library(shiny).

This works wonderfully well and now i want turn the D3 code into modular objects which will save me a lot of coding and makes it usable by others. My idea is to get to this:

```
<r-d3-gauge id="G1" data="[1,2,3]"></r-d3-gauge>
<r-d3-gauge id="G2" data="[4,5,6]"></r-d3-gauge>
```

And i have the two gauges that i can position with CSS or just inject them into shiny with  HTML(....). Ok this should be simple using AngularJS.

But i can not get AngularJS to work in R shiny. 
I made this test code:
(a www folder with d3.js and angular.min.1.4.3.js next to server.r/ui.r)

ui.r

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(src = "d3.js"))
  ,tags$head(tags$script(src = "angular.min.1.4.3.js"))
  ,htmlOutput("JS")
  ,htmlOutput("HTML")
))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
# HTML
 output$HTML <- renderUI({
  html <- ''
  html <- paste0(html,'
   <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
   <h4>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></h4>
   <h4 ng-bind="name"></h4>
   <h4>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name2"></h4>
   <h4>You wrote: {{name2}}</h4>
  ')
  HTML(html)
 })

# JS
 output$JS <- renderUI({
  html <- "<script language='JavaScript'>"
  html <- paste0(html,'
   if(typeof angular == "undefined") {
    console.log("angular == undefined");
   } else {
    console.log("angular == defined");
    console.log(angular.version.full)
   }
   if (window.jQuery) {  
    console.log("jQuery == defined");
    console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
   } else {
    console.log("jQuery == undefined");
   }
  d3.select("body")
    .attr("ng-app","")
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
     $(this).hide();
    });
  });
  </script>')
 HTML(html)
})
})
```

This creates a shiny app with html code that is fine, the test shows that

```
angular == defined
1.4.3
jQuery == defined
2.1.4
```

So no problem there. jQuery works fine (you can click on "Input something in the input box:" and it is hidden) but if i enter text it does not show up. If i try something like:

```
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name2"></p>
<p>You wrote: {{ name2 }}</p>
```

it wil show You wrote: {{ name2 }} without subsetting the {{name2}} part.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK this works:

ui.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(includeHTML("static.html")))
```

server.r

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {})
```

static.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>
    <script language='JavaScript'>

      if(typeof angular == "undefined") {
        console.log("angular == undefined");
      } else {
        console.log("angular == defined");
        console.log(angular.version.full)
      }

      if (window.jQuery) {  
        console.log("jQuery == defined");
        console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
      } else {
        console.log("jQuery == undefined");
      }

      d3.select("body").attr("ng-app","")
    </script>

      <p>Input something in the input box:</p>
      <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
      <p ng-bind="name"></p>
      <h4>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name2"></h4>
      <h4>You wrote: {{name2}}</h4>

  </body>
</html>
```

Et voila, Up and Running ! :^)

Comment: thanks for sharing! i wonder how one can read variables from the `static.html` into `R`, or write `R` variables into the `static.html`.

Comment: @zhibo do you want to do this only at startup or in a asynchronous continuous way ?

Comment: asynchronous continuous way

Comment: @zhibo OK then you have to add javascript and use: Shiny.onInputChange("Robject", JavascriptObject); in R you can catch this with: observe({Robject <- input$Robject}) Every time that the Javascript element JavascriptObject is changed at the moment it passes this code an update is send to R. After that you can use R to update the webpage. (easier said then done but if you if you take some time to study and learn you can solve this =^)

Comment: Thanks for your example @irJvV. Considering @zhibo question, where should I put the ``Shiny.onInputChange`` in the javascript? Currently it looks like this but the slider doesn't work when I add the ``Shiny.onInputChange``:   
  ``<script language='JavaScript'> 
   var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);
  Shiny.onInputChange("Robject", data);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $modal) {
  //Minimal slider config
  $scope.minSlider = {
        value: 10
    };
});
  </script>``

Comment: @Tim_Utrecht the action Shiny.onInputChange(..) is done on passing the code so you should incorporate it into an action that is re-evaluated each time a json object is changed in javascript.

Comment: So it seems like R/shiny is evaluating code/objects within {{}} brackets as of now -- this is getting in the way of the angular code obviously. @irJvV was this not an issue at the time of this answer? I just tried to use your code snippet above and nothing is working.

Comment: @Taylor just tested the code with the latest version of R and it does not work for me either =^(. I left the Rshiny/Angular approach and code everything in Javascript now on top of R shiny.Some javascript libraries collide with the R shiny bootstrapping i guess.

Comment: Ok @irJvV thank you for checking. I think I'll use pure javascript and maybe some d3/jquery instead of angular.

Comment: @Taylor, be carefull with the jquery, the Shiny bootstrap also uses jquery. If you take a look at the loading of a shiny web page (see developer tools) you can find this. I do load jquery too but the loading order is quite important.

Comment: @irJvV noted, much appreciated

Comment: **This works for me!** (not within Rstudio viewer but in browser): R 3.4.2, shiny_1.0.5, angularjs 1.4.0, jQuery 1.12.4, d3 3.5.17