# Custom sliders in Shiny

Tags: angularjs, r, slider, shiny

I'm really frustrated by the limited sliders `shiny` currently provides. I would like to have a slider that:

1. Has both an inputvalue and a slidervalue that correspond, like the sliders from `angularjs`: bottom of [this link](http://angular-slider.github.io/angularjs-slider/index.html) and [here](http://danielcrisp.github.io/angular-rangeslider/demo/)
2. Doesn't refresh the entire every millisecond I try to find to right value. I want it to be reactive, but not 25 times when I'm looking for the right value.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit:**
Managed to get the AngularJS slider working after the hint below and quite some tries. Please find the repo [here](https://github.com/tbenschop/AngularJS). I although don't manage to get the data back into R. You should do that with the `Shiny.onInputChange` function. I tried it like this:

```
        <script language='JavaScript'>          
            var app = angular.module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);
            Shiny.onInputChange("Robject", app);
        app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout, $modal) {
        //Minimal slider config
        $scope.minSlider = {
        value: 10
    };

});
        </script>
```

and of course played with the `app` object name but the slider just keeps failing.

Comment: 1. Doesn't the current slider already show the value on the sliding toggle? https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/sliders.html 2. How would you like shiny to know when to refresh? You could always add a button that runs your calculation only when you click it. Alternatively, you can add javascript that binds to a mouseout event, which then sends the input value to shiny when your cursor has left the slider

Comment: @waterling Yes, but I don't only want to show it, I also want to be able to change it with a ``numericInput`` like input. Like you see in the ``angularjs`` examples.  2. I don't want a button, but the ``javascript`` you describe sounds perfect. I'll investigate on that.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31962802/r-shiny-angularjs-working

Comment: Thanks @s.brunel that worked. Now I have the same issue as a commenter on that post, to get values back in R! Please find my edited answer.

Comment: https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guys from dreamR have released a package that solves many of the missing widgets: 
https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets